# Visual Studio Without Template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've Installed the VS2017, but templates do not appear, only 'Blank Solution'. 
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, without success.
Has anyone ever been in this situation?

Image:
[image: Template]

[image: Install]

Comment: When using the Visual Studio Community installer have you selected '.NET desktop development' under the 'Workloads' tab? [Like so](https://i.imgur.com/wDoPtcj.png).

Comment: i Did and unfortunately stay the same.

Comment: And just to be clear, when you try and create a new project the tree on the left side of the window does not contain an item called 'Visual C#' under 'Installed'? IE it only contains 'Other Project Types > Visual Studio Solutions' (which contains 'Blank Solution').

Comment: Yes. exactly like this.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? and can you go to `Add/Remove Programs` and choose to Modify VS2017 and the show us a screenshot of that screen, too?

Comment: I'll check the screenshot. However I did get it to appear after install vs2015, and copy the _'ProjectTemplates'_ folder and paste in vs2017. But it does not seem right to me, like is missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently microsoft solved the problem. after updating to last version it returned the information.

[image]